# how to send email when condition be comes true using python

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm doing a face mask detection project. i have already trained the dataset and created the model. then i deployed that model to detect the masked face. actually its working as expected.
now i want to send an email when the system detects a person without mask and show a warning message.
here is the code :

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
import smtplib
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

def detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (224, 224),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()
    print(detections.shape)

    
    faces = []
    locs = []
    preds = []

    
    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        if confidence > 0.5:
            
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)

            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    
    if len(faces) > 0:
        
        faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)

    
    return (locs, preds)


prototxtPath = r"face_detector\deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)


maskNet = load_model("mask_detector.model")


print("[INFO] starting video stream...")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()


while True:
    
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    (locs, preds) = detect_and_predict_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred
        
        label = "Mask" if mask > withoutMask else "No Mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "Mask" else (0, 0, 255)

        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)
        

        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
        
        if(label == "No Mask"):
            messagebox.showwarning("warning access denied","please put your mask.")
            with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)as smtp:
                smtp.ehlo()
                smtp.starttls()
                smtp.ehlo()
                smtp.login('helpdeskadhi@gmail.com','pnfnvboatmczopkn')
                subject = "Warning"
                body = "one visitor violated the rule."
                msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
                smtp.sendmail('helpdeskadhi@gmail.com','helpdeskadhi@gmail.com',msg)
        else:
            pass
            break


    
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

when i run this code it is still working as before. but its not sending any email and not showing any warning message.

Comment: Just looking at the format string, `label` is not going to be `"No Mask"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program seems to be fine. As i can see, you are using gmail smtp. In this case, you need to turn on less secure apps option.
Here's the link : https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Turn this on, and try again. Hope this helps :>

Comment: but i have already turned on less secure app option.